# parsing through dict to separate keys and values

Tags: python

I have code that looks through a folder full of tsv files and grabs the name of the file as the key and the column headers as the values in the dict.

```
row1 =[]
listdict=[] 
for f in files: 
    with open(dir_path  +'/'+f, 'rU') as file: 
        reader = csv.reader(file) 
        row1 = next(reader) 
        dict = {f: row1} 
        listdict.append(dict)
```

when trying to access the dict `listdict['file_name.tsv']`, I get an error

```
*** TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

when using ints `listdict[0]`, I can't seem to access values separately as they're all clumped together as 1 value.

```
{'file_name.tsv': ['header1\theader2\theader3\theader4']}
```

How can I access each header separately. My goal is to create a csv output that lists the filename and all of the associated headers.

Comment: It seems that you've already corrected your error in your code, by using `append`. Also, `listdict` is a list, not a dict. Also, you'd be better off using variable names that are not types (it's a terrible idea to name a variable `list` or `dict` or `file`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `list` is used when you want an ordered list of elements.

A `dict` is used when you want an unordered set of key-value pairs.

If you want to query up file headers by filename (ex. `listdict['file_name.tsv']`) you will need to use a `dict`. Additionally, if you want to query up individual file headers in a file, you will need to use a `list` to retain the order:

```
listdict={}
for f in files:
    with open(dir_path  +'/'+f, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
        row1 = next(reader)  # stores first row of tsv file in a list
        listdict[f] = row1
```

An entry in `listdict` will look like:

```
{'file_name.tsv': ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4']}
```

`listdict['file_name.tsv']` will give you `['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4']`.

`listdict['file_name.tsv'][0]` will give you the value `'header1'`.

Comment: You can also use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to preserve the order of the items in the dictionary :)

Comment: I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` error message. My output is actually `{'filename.tsv': ['header1\theader2\theader3\theader4']}'` with \t inbetween headers. I've made the edit above as well.

Comment: Sorry, it should be separated automatically by the reader. Edited the answer, should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a list by doing `listdicts = []`.

Create a dictionary instead: `listdicts = {}`.

```
 listdict={}
 for f in files: 
     with open(dir_path  +'/'+f, 'r') as file: 
         reader = csv.reader(file) 
         listdict[f] = next(reader).split() # split will split the headers by `\t`
```

and access the corresponding first header with `listdict['file_name.tsv'][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this

```
filedict={}
for f in files: 
    with open(dir_path  +'/'+f, 'rU') as file: 
        reader = csv.reader(file) 
        row1 = next(reader) 
        filedict[f] = row1
```